# cant do hover inside image link with css

Tags: html, css

i try to put hover in my image link but failed, can u guys fix it for me

it's my code

```
<div class="container" id="link">
    <table border="1" width="1140px" height="600px" id="link" >
        <tr id="link">
            <td valign="top" id="link" >
                <table border="0" width="100%" id="link">
```

and this is my css

```
#link A:link {text-decoration:none;  color:#000; background-color:none;}
#link A:lvisited {text-decoration:none;  color:#000; background-color:none;}
#link A:active {text-decoration:none;  color:#000; background-color:none;}
#link A:hover {text-decoration:none;  color:#D8CCDE; background-color:none;;
                        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
                        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
                        -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease;
                        -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease;
                        -o-transition: all 0.7s ease;
                        transition: all 0.7s ease;}

    .clearfix{
    clear :both;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your image and where is your `a`? id must be unique use classes

Comment: Why do you have multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: <td align="center"   valign="top" ><a href ="index.php"  tittle="Home" id="image1"><img src="image/home.png" width="85px" height="120px"    ></a></td>this is thelink

Comment: Can you provide us with the complete code? You can edit the original question to do so.

Comment: Do you mean hover the mouse pointer to the image?

Answer (score 0):

like this? as other answer said, id's should be unique, keep styles seperate and valign attr deprecated

```css
a img:hover{border:2px solid red;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="http://www.google.com">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100" />
              </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: also instead of 3 declarations doing the same thing, comma seperate them `#link A:link ,#link A:visited ,#link A:active {text-decoration:none;  color:#000; background-color:none;}` and take the l of the visited psuedo